# How to call recursive query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like following

```
  emp_id    emp_name    manager_id
    A1          A           C1
    B1          B           C1
    C1          C           D1
    D1          D           F1
    E1          E           F1
    F1          F           G1
    G1          G
```

- If some one ask who report to C1, it should return B1, A1
- If some one ask who report to D1, it should return C1,B1,A1
- If some one ask who report to F1, it should return E1,D1,C1,A1, B1
- If some one ask who report to G1, it should return F1,E1,D1,C1,A1, B1

I am new to write sql query.Can you please help me to write a query for meet the above requirement.Thanks in advanced.

Regards,
Pankaj

Comment: `I am new to write sql query` ... all the more reason why you should be trying to solve this yourself before coming here.  You'll learn very little by being spoon-fed a completely working answer.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/

Comment: Conditions in sql can help you to use inner filtering for this situation. Just be sure to using conditions correct. If you stuck in your process, ask your question to StackOverFlow community.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question and add a bit more information. Could you let uw know what query(s) you've tried already yourself?

Comment: Thanks all for your all support now I can write cte query.

Comment: @PankajKarmakar Accept/Upvote the answers which were of help to you. That is StackOverflow's ways of saying thanks. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH temp(empid,empname,empManagerID)  
AS  
(  
SELECT 'A1','A','C1' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'B1','B','C1' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'C1','C','D1' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'D1','D','F1' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'E1','E','F1' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'F1','F','G1' UNION ALL   
SELECT 'G1','G',NULL  
)  
, CTE_Recrusive  
AS  
(  
SELECT empid,empname,empManagerID  
FROm TEMP  
WHERE empManagerID='G1'  
UNION ALL  
SELECT  t.empid,t.empname,t.empManagerID  
FROm CTE_Recrusive c  
INNER JOIN TEMP t on c.empid = t.empManagerID  
)  
select * from  CTE_Recrusive
```

Answer (score 0):

This query here shows who the immediate reporting manager of an employee is. Perhaps you could add something to your question to make it more understandable.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT emp_id
        ,emp_name
        ,manager_id
    FROM emp
    WHERE emp_id = 'G1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT E.emp_id
        ,E.emp_name
        ,E.manager_id
    FROM emp E
    INNER JOIN cte c ON E.emp_id = c.emp_id
    )
SELECT emp_id
    ,emp_name
    ,cast(coalesce(manager_id, 'Boss') AS VARCHAR(max) FROM cte)
```

Comment: check ur code ,you didn't use union all and your code will not get expected result

Comment: As I already mentioned, this code will give only a single reporting manager.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive cte

```
;WITH CTE_Recursive(emp_id,emp_name,manager_id)
AS
(
SELECT 'A1','A','C1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B1','B','C1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1','C','D1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'D1','D','F1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'E1','E','F1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'F1','F','G1' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'G1','G',NULL
)
,CTE_Result
AS
(
SELECT  Emp_ID,
        Emp_name,
        CAST(Emp_name  AS VARCHAR(100))AS Boss
FROM CTE_Recursive
WHERE manager_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT  e.Emp_ID,
        e.Emp_name,
        CAST(Boss+ '\'+e.Emp_name  AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Boss

FROM CTE_Result c
INNER JOIN CTE_Recursive e
ON e.manager_id=c.Emp_ID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_Result
```